# Blockchain.info API - Check transactions from one address to another

Tags: api, blockchain.info

Using the [blockchain.info API](https://blockchain.info/api), how can I check the transactions from one address to another, including the number of confirmations?

**Clarification:** I have one address let us say. I want to programmatically check new transactions, without running a wallet and a full node on my computer. So my address is fixed. The sender address is also fixed. So, given 2 addresses, get all the transactions from one to the other. And ideally including the number of confirmations.

Comment: Can you clarify, are you just looking for all the TxIDs? UTXOs only? Need it be Blockchain.info?

Comment: Additional point to clarify, there is no from address, so you don't have an easy way of looking for transactions from one address to another, which is how I understand the question.

Comment: @Drazisil That's right; the easiest way I'd know is to get the TxIDs for *from* and *to*, Txs_from and Txs_to, respectively. Then find the intersection of these two TxID sets

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pybitcointools](https://github.com/vbuterin/pybitcointools) `history(address)`. Note that this function has bugs, so try [my fork](https://github.com/wizardofozzie/pybitcointools) instead.

Or, the API request for *12c6DSiU4Rq3P4ZxziKxzrL5LmMBrzjrJX* would be:

```
https://blockchain.info/address/12c6DSiU4Rq3P4ZxziKxzrL5LmMBrzjrJX?format=json&offset=0
```

If there's more than 50 results, you'd change `offset=50`.

I'll provide more details if required.

My personal recommendation would be to use this API call, as there's no offset issues:

```
https://bitcoin.toshi.io/api/v0/addresses/12c6DSiU4Rq3P4ZxziKxzrL5LmMBrzjrJX/transactions
```

Comment: @Solver I'll check now mate, just so I know, are you familiar with Python? If so, I'll post the code instead of "pseudocoding" the answer